# Unique vs MAX in SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with three columns:

```
PERSON 
VISITOR
DATE
```

The table is basically a transactional table. The following is true:

1. There are multiple rows per person
2. There are multiple rows per visitor
3. There are multiple rows of a given person/visitor combination.
4. Assumed unique person/date combination

What I need is

- I want visitor for each Person's MAX Date.
- I cannot have multiple persons in the output.
- Person must be unique.
- visitor may repeat.

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON, VISITOR ORDER BY Date DESC) row_num,
    PERSON,
    VISITOR as VISITOR
FROM 
    `TABLE`
ORDER BY 
    PERSON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this...  not sure I fully understand question.  Sample data /expected results would help.

You said you wanted only the 1 person with the visitor per max date so the row_num of 1 will be the record w/ the max date. and since we partition by person it will not matter if person A had 3 visitors.  only the person and their Most recent  visitor will be listed.

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON ORDER BY Date DESC) row_num
     , PERSON
     , VISITOR as VISITOR
FROM `TABLE`)

SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE row_Num = 1
```

I think this can be done with a cross apply too though i'm not as good at using them yet...

```
SELECT A.Person, A.Visitor, A.Date 
FROM table A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM TABLE B
             WHERE A.Person = B.Person 
               and A.Visitor = B.Visitor
               and A.Date = B.Date
             ORDER BY DATE DESC) C
```

Essentially the inner query runs for each record on the outer query; thus only the top most record will be returned thus the newest date.

Comment: THanks XQbert.  It answered my question and gave me something else to learn.  Most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.* from myTable as a inner join (
SELECT person, max(date) as maxDate from myTable group by person
) as b 
on a.date = b.maxDate
and a.person = b.person;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am weak in reading and writing English.
In my opinion the answer may be:

```
SELECT `PERSON`, `VISITOR`, MAX(`DATE`) AS `DATE`
FROM `TABLE`
GROUP BY `PERSON`, `VISITOR`;
```

Comment: I don't think that you want to group by both person and visitor, Person was unique, implying one row per person.